# Integer division in awk

Tags: awk, integer, division

I want to divide two numbers in `awk`, using integer division, i.e truncating the result. For example

```
k = 3 / 2
print k
```

should print `1`

According to [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Ops.html),

> Division; because all numbers in awk are floating-point numbers, the result is ***not rounded to an integer***

Is there any workaround to get an integer value?

The reason is that I want to get the *middle element* of an array with *integer* indexes [0 to num-1].

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the `int` function to get the integer part of the result, truncated toward 0. This produces the nearest integer to the result, located between the result and 0. For example, `int(3/2)` is 1, `int(-3/2)` is -1.

Source: [The AWK Manual - Numeric Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html)

Comment: This doesn't count as integer division, integer division has a strict guarantee based on remainder. This is just "truncation"

Answer (score 15):

In simple cases, you can safely use `int()` which truncates towards zero<sup>1</sup>:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print int(3 / 2) }'    # prints 1
gawk 'BEGIN { print int(-3 / 2) }'  # prints -1; not guaranteed in POSIX awk
```

Keep in mind that awk always uses double-precision floating point numbers<sup>2</sup> and floating-point arithmetic<sup>3</sup>, though. The only way you can get integers and integer arithmetic is to use external tools, e.g. the standard `expr` utility:

```
awk 'BEGIN { "expr 3 / 2" | getline result; print result; }'    # prints 1
```

This is really *awk*ward, long, slow, … but safe and portable.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In [POSIX awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_12), truncation to zero is guaranteed only for positive arguments: *int(x) — Return the argument truncated to an integer. Truncation shall be toward 0 when x>0.* [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Numeric-Functions) (gawk) uses truncation toward zero even for negative numbers: *int(x) — Return the nearest integer to x, located between x and zero and truncated toward zero. For example, int(3) is 3, int(3.9) is 3, int(-3.9) is -3, and int(-3) is -3 as well.*</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Numeric expressions are specified as double-precision floats in [Expressions in awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02) in POSIX.</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> *All arithmetic shall follow the semantics of floating-point arithmetic as specified by the ISO C standard (see [Concepts Derived from the ISO C Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_01_02)).* — [POSIX awk: Arithmetic functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_12)</sup>

---

If you choose to use floats, you should know about their quirks and be ready to spot them and avoid related bugs. Several scary examples:

- Unrepresentable numbers:

  ```
  awk 'BEGIN { x = 0.875; y = 0.425; printf("%0.17g, %0.17g\n", x, y) }'
  # prints 0.875, 0.42499999999999999
  ```
- [Round-off errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) accumulation:

  ```
  awk 'BEGIN{s=0; for(i=1;i<=100000;i++)s+=0.3; printf("%.10f, %d\n",s,int(s))}'
  # prints 29999.9999999506, 29999
  ```
- Round-off errors ruin comparisons:

  ```
  awk 'BEGIN { print (0.1 + 12.2 == 12.3) }'    # prints 0
  ```
- Precision decreases with magnitude, causing infinite loops:

  ```
  awk 'BEGIN { for (i=10^16; i<10^16+5; i++) printf("%d\n", i) }'
  # prints 10000000000000000 infinitely many times
  ```

Read more on how floats work:

1. Stack Overflow tags [floating-point](/questions/tagged/floating-point) wiki
2. Wikipedia article [Floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)
3. [GNU awk arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic) – contains both info on the specific implementation and general knowledge

Comment: I guess a way to overcome the floating errors (for relatively small numbers) would be to do `int(3/2+0.25)`.

Comment: @user000001 Adding a constant does not solve the problem, it actually adds a new one. `awk 'BEGIN {print int(7/8), int (7/8 + 0.25)}'` produces `0 1`.

Comment: Yes it would have to be less than `1/(d/2)`, where `d` is the denominator. As long as this value is larger than the floating error, it should work.

Answer (score 6):

Safe and quick awk integer division can be done with:

```
q=(n-n%d)/d+(n<0)
```

Comment: +1. Clever trick, I'll give you that. I wonder if it safe for precision errors, as @Palec explains...

Comment: +1 This implements a `ceil` type of rounding (toward +inf). Other mathematically correct mod concepts and consequently rounding methods do exist. Some other method may be preferable.

Comment: @sorontar At least in my system, this is not equivalent to a `ceil` function

Comment: Hm: Using Gawk 5.1 `gawk -v n=-1 -v d=1 'BEGIN{print(n-n%d)/d+(n<0)}'` gives 0, `bash -c 'echo $((-1/1))'` of course prints -1.